# Detecting a face and saving the detected face in OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, face-detection

I am trying to detect the face in the image and trying to save the detected face as an image in OpenCV.

Having some problems in the detectfaces function below.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <cxcore.h>

CvHaarClassifierCascade *cascade;
CvMemStorage            *storage;

void detectFaces( IplImage *img );

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  //CvCapture *capture;
  IplImage  *img;//*out;
  int       key = 0;
  char      *filename = "C:/OpenCV2.1/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";

  cascade = ( CvHaarClassifierCascade* )cvLoad( filename, 0, 0, 0 );
  storage = cvCreateMemStorage( 0 );
  img     = cvLoadImage("Yurico.png");

  assert( cascade && storage && img );

  cvNamedWindow( "video:", 1 );
  //cvNamedWindow( "video1:", 1 );
  //out = detectFaces( img );
  detectFaces( img );
  cvWaitKey( 0 );
  //cvShowImage( "video", out );
  cvDestroyWindow( "video:" );
  //cvDestroyWindow( "video1:" );
  cvReleaseImage( &img );
  cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade( &cascade );
  cvReleaseMemStorage( &storage );

  return 0;
}

void detectFaces( IplImage *img )
{
    int i;
     CvRect *r;
    CvSeq *faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(
            img,
            cascade,
            storage,
            1.1,
            3,
            0 /*CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNNING*/,
            cvSize( 40, 40) );

    for( i = 0 ; i < ( faces ? faces->total : 0 ) ; i++ ) {
        CvRect *r = ( CvRect* )cvGetSeqElem( faces, i );
        cvRectangle( img,
                     cvPoint( r->x, r->y ),
                     cvPoint( r->x + r->width, r->y + r->height ),
                     CV_RGB( 255, 0, 0 ), 1, 8, 0 );
    }

    //cvShowImage( "video:", img );
    cvSetImageROI(img, CvRect *r);

    IplImage *img2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 
                              img->depth, 
                               img->nChannels);

    cvSaveImage("Lakshmen.jpg",img2); 
}
```

Have a error saying this :

```
 Error  1   error C2664: 'cvSetImageROI' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'CvRect *' to 'CvRect'   c:\users\hp\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\facedetect\facedetect\facedetect.cpp  67  1   facedetect
```

Want to save the region of interest into another image. Any corrections or improvements do tell me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to pass a CvRect and not a CvRect*, so you do not need the pointer (*) before r.
and since it is already a cvRect you should just write:

```
 cvSetImageROI(img, &r);
```

Comment: well a cvRect is created like this: CvRect rect = cvRect(25, 25, img2->width, img2->height); you are just casting a cvSeq* to a cvRect*.        you need to understand where the face begind and this is the first point of the rect, then the size in the sequence will be the size of the rect. still the error is there and not in the setROI

Comment: try CvRect r =CvRect (startingpoint.x, startingpoint.y, 40, 40); the size of the face seems always 40x40 from your code. now I don't know where you store the starting point of the rectangle in which the face lies (probably in "faces" you have all the values you need)

Answer (score 2):

`cvSetImageROI()` takes a `cvRect` as the 2nd argument, and it uses it as input parameter to clip the image to that area.

In other words, you need to create a `cvRect` with valid info. You can do it before calling the function, or inline:

```
cvSetImageROI(img_corr, cvRect(x_pos, y_pos, width, height));
```

I also noticed that in your code, you create `CvRect* r;` on at least 3 diferent locations inside the same function. Bad practice! Tip: create variables in your code at the moment you are going to use them, not before that.

Comment: how do u link the detected face region together with the cvSetImageROI?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `CvRect *r` as `r=(CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem( faces,i)` and after the for-loop write the two lines

```
cvSetImageROI(img, cvRect(r->x,r->y,r->width,r->height));
cvSaveImage("C1.jpg",img);
```